# Sublime Text syntax highlighting sections titles as bold in the source

Tags: sublime-text, syntax-highlighting

Currently the section commands are coloured blue (using the Monokai theme). I would like to add more emphasis to sectioning commands in the source code when open in Sublime Text 3, similar to the effect [illustrated in the Emacs answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides/356#356).

I installed the `PackageResourceViewer` plugin and opened `LaTeX.sublime-syntax` resource. I see:

```
  sections:
    - match: |-
        (?x)
        (
          (\\)
          (?:
            (?:sub){0,2}section
            | (?:sub)?paragraph
            | chapter|part|addpart
            | addchap|addsec|minisec
          )
          (?:\*)?
        )
        (?:
          (\[)([^\[]*?)(\])               # optional Title
        )?
        (\{)
      captures:
        1: support.function.section.latex
        2: punctuation.definition.backslash.latex
        3: punctuation.definition.group.brace.begin.latex
        4: entity.name.section.latex
        5: punctuation.definition.group.brace.end.latex
        6: punctuation.definition.group.brace.begin.latex
      push:
        - meta_scope: meta.section.latex
        - meta_content_scope: entity.name.section.latex
        - match: '\}'
          scope: punctuation.definition.group.brace.end.latex
          pop: true
        - include: main
```

But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in Sublime Text currently. The `.sublime-syntax` file just attaches "scope" names to the different parts of a LaTeX file (so that in e.g. `\section[One]{...}` the "One" gets the name `entity.name.section.latex`). It doesn't do any styling/colouring itself. As far as I know that side of things is controlled entirely by a colour scheme (a `.tmTheme`, for example Monokai) *using* the scope names. I know they can choose different colours and sometimes bold/italic, but I've never seen changing the font size.

Comment: Just bold without a change in font size would be an improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Overview

The way Sublime Text styles files is to separate the semantic meaning and the actual rendering. This is similar to LaTeX: you have a command `\section{...}`—indicating the intent—versus the actual rendering, perhaps `\textbf{\huge ...}` for a very simple example.

A `.sublime-syntax` file is only supposed to attach *semantic* meaning to parts of a document ("this is a section"), whilst the job of deciding how to render things ("this is bold") on screen belongs to colour scheme `.tmThemes` files. (Of course in practice things are not so clean, and you'll see a mix of the two in `.sublime-syntax` files. In a perfect world this wouldn't happen.)

So you have two options:

- tweak the syntax file, analogous to replacing every instance of `\section{...}` with `\textbf{\huge ...}` to get bold sections. Not recommended, but I'll talk about how you could do it here.
- tweak the colour scheme file, analogous to changing the *definition* of `\section` to embolden sections.

### Tweak the syntax

Here we simply change the relevant parts of `LaTeX.sublime-syntax` to e.g. `markup.bold.latex` (see [this](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/scope_naming.html) link for a discussion about scope names in Sublime Text). The altered lines are the ones with comments `# ...` after them.

```yaml
sections:
  - match: |-
      (?x)
      (
        (\\)
        (?:
          (?:sub){0,2}section
          | (?:sub)?paragraph
          | chapter|part|addpart
          | addchap|addsec|minisec
        )
        (?:\*)?
      )
      (?:
        (\[)([^\[]*?)(\])
      )?
      (\{)
    captures:
      1: support.function.section.latex
      2: punctuation.definition.backslash.latex
      3: punctuation.definition.group.brace.begin.latex
      4: entity.name.section.latex markup.bold.latex  # this is for the reference [...]
      5: punctuation.definition.group.brace.end.latex
      6: punctuation.definition.group.brace.begin.latex
    push:
      - meta_scope: meta.section.latex
      - meta_content_scope: entity.name.section.latex markup.bold.latex  # this is for the title {...}
      - match: '\}'
        scope: punctuation.definition.group.brace.end.latex
        pop: true
      - include: main
```

(I kept the old scope `entity.name.section.latex` around in-case things rely on it, but putting `markup.bold.latex` after it means that the bold has priority over it.)

Results may (will) vary across different colour schemes, for example some don't understand what `markup.bold` means. You mention Monokai, the default version doesn't handle `markup.bold`, but e.g. [Monokai Extended](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/sublime-monokai-extended) understands does.

## Tweak the colour scheme

The other option is to tweak the colour scheme itself. Colour schemes in Sublime Text are `.tmTheme` files, basically xml files. They have this sort of structure:

```xml
... (preamble stuff)
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>name</key> <string>Colour Scheme Name</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <array>

    <dict>
      <key>settings</key> <dict> ... (general settings) </dict>
    </dict>

    <dict>
      <key>name</key> <string>First Scope Name</string>
      <key>scope</key> <string>first.scope</string>
      <key>settings</key> <dict> ... </dict>
    </dict>

    ...

    <dict>
      <key>name</key> <string>Last Scope Name</string>
      <key>scope</key> <string>last.scope</string>
      <key>settings</key> <dict> ... </dict>
    </dict>

  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Taking a look at the contents of the default `Monokai.tmTheme`, the relevant part for us is this entry in the `array`:

```xml
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>Entity name</string>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>entity.name - (entity.name.filename | entity.name.section | entity.name.tag | entity.name.label)</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>fontStyle</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#A6E22E</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

This is what controls the style our `entity.name.section.latex` scope gets. What we can do is put in a new rule specifically targeting LaTeX sections:

```xml
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>LaTeX section entity name</string>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>entity.name.section.latex</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>fontStyle</key>
    <string>bold</string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#A6E22E</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

I don't know whether order matters here, to be safe I would put this in the `<array> ... </array>` list *before* the "Entity name" entry. Also, I don't know whether it's possible to change the font size; if it *can* be done, then this would surely be the place to do it.

Comment: You should change the colorscheme not the syntax definition in such cases. The colorscheme should manage the appearance and th syntax definition should provide scopes. In addition you may miss future updates if you change it.

Comment: I agree. I did want to show changing the syntax definition anyway since, while it is less correct, it's quick and easy.

Comment: Yes, it a good and detailed answer. I just wanted to emphasize, that the 2nd part is more desirable.